# USB mouse doesn't work/gets stuck on Ub 12.10, kernel 3.8.1 and Asus N56V

Tags: 12.10, usb, mouse

All of my ports are USB3 ports. I installed Ubuntu and the mouse doesn't work, restarted, still doesn't work, upgraded kernel to 3.8.1, no change. Touchpad works fine.

Some debug info:

There is a `/dev/input/mouse0`.

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0458:003a KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) NetScroll+ Mini Traveler / Genius NetScroll 120
```

`dmesg | tail -n10` (I did the disconnect to show it recognizes it)

```
[ 1124.544481] usb 3-1: >USB disconnect, device number 7
[ 1130.511890] usb 3-1: >new low-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
```

Can you please give me an advice how to make the mouse work? Thank you

EDIT:
Go to BIOS (hold F2 on start), find Advanced -> USB Configuration -> enable XHCI Pre-boot mode. This makes mouse work until suspending the laptop, then it gets stuck. Reconnecting helps but it is tedious.

Comment: Have you tried other USB devices?

Comment: Good question. Yes, a Genius keyboard and it works. Unfortunately I don't have anything else here to try.